# PySpark Iterate Rows and Drop Rows with Specified Value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | [{id: 1000, abbreviatedId: 1, name: “John", planet: “Earth”, solarsystem: “Milky Way”, universe: “this one”, continent: {id: 33, country: “China", Capital: “Bejing”}, otherId: 400, language: “Cantonese”, species: 23409, creature: “Human”}] |
| Bye | [{id: 2000, abbreviatedId: 2, name: “James", planet: “Earth”, solarsystem: “Milky Way”, universe: “this one”, continent: {id: 33, country: “Russia", Capital: “Moscow”}, otherId: 500, language: “Russian”, species: 12308, creature: “Human”}] |

How do I iterate through the rows of the dataframe to drop all rows with `country: "China"` before writing to external location?

I have tried

```
if df.select(array_contains(col("columnb.continent.country"), "China")) != True:
    df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("file://path/")
```

and

```
for row in df.rdd.collect():
    if df.select(array_contains(col("columnb.continent.country"), "China")) != True:
      df.drop(row)

df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("file://path/")
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `Column B`?

Comment: array<struct<id:bigint,abbreviatedId:bigint,name:string,planet:string,solarsystem:string,universe:string,continent:struct<id:bigint,country:string,capital:string>,otherId:bigint,language:string,species:bigint,creature:string>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is using [exists](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#exists) array function.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    [
      [
        Row(**{"id": 1000, "abbreviatedId": 1, "name": "John", "planet": "Earth", "solarsystem": "Milky Way", "universe": "this one", "continent": Row(**{"id": 33, "country": "China", "Capital": "Bejing"}), "otherId": 400, "language": "Cantonese", "species": 23409, "creature": "Human"}), 
        Row(**{"id": 1001, "abbreviatedId": 2, "name": "Alex", "planet": "Mars", "solarsystem": "Milky Way", "universe": "this one", "continent": Row(**{"id": 34, "country": "Japan", "Capital": "Tokyo"}), "otherId": 400, "language": "Japanese", "species": 23409, "creature": "Human"})
    ]
]], ["b"])


df.filter(expr("not exists(b, x -> x.continent.country == 'China')"))
```

The syntax `Row(**dict)` will create an instance of [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.html#pyspark.sql.Row) through argument unpacking.